# controlling typography in footnote and endnote numbering with biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex, fontspec, typography, endnotes, biblatex-chicago

i'm trying to remove the square brackets around the footnote/endnote numbers in the body text, and also make their typeface consistent with the body text (in this case, Minion Pro oldstyle numerals)—right now, they appear to be lining numerals in some other typeface.

here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper]{book}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{longtable}


\usepackage[width=5.6in, height=8.2in, letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\parindent=1.5em

\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}


% specify typography and pagenumbering 
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Numbers=OldStyle]{Minion Pro}
    \pagenumbering{arabic}

    % uses biblatex-chicago, declares bibliographic resource
    \usepackage[notes,notetype=endonly,isbn=false,doi=false,url=false,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
    \addbibresource[location=remote]{https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/900449/bibtex/bibliographies/master.bib} 
    \usepackage{endnotes}
    % formats endnotes
        \renewcommand{\makeenmark}{\hbox{$^{[\theenmark]}$}}
        \makeatletter
        \def\enoteformat{%
        \rightskip\z@ \leftskip\z@ \parindent=1.8em
        \leavevmode{\setbox\z@=\lastbox}\llap{\theenmark.\enskip}%
        }
        \makeatother

        \let\footnote=\endnote
        \let\cite=\autocite
        %\renewcommand{\autocite}[1]{\footnote{\cite{#1}}}


\begin{document}


\setstretch{1.25}

Where Michelin might have a ten or so reviewers per country (Michelin does not disclose exact numbers, though a former employee has written about the structure of the reviewer teams\autocite{remy.2004}), the 50 Best jury is unpaid and consists of about a thousand people around the world, each of whom nominates and votes on the composition of the list.\footnote{This information about the jury, known as the World's 50 Best Restaurants Academy, was provided by the World's 50 Best Restaurants and is accurate as of June 2017.} 

\theendnotes
\clearpage
\setstretch{1.0}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

which produces this: [image]
(note the lining numerals and the different typeface in the in-text numbering)

i can't find anything in the documentation for either `endnotes` or `biblatex-chicago` on controlling typography.

Comment: Your MWE won't work because `\end{document}` is missing. Please check if more is missing in your example.

Comment: Do you want the square brackets in the endnotes at the end? Or could you just not do `\renewcommand{\makeenmark}{\hbox{$^{[\theenmark]}$}}`?

Comment: @moewe you're absolutely right. i pasted that in with some controls for the margins in the endnotes themselves and didn't see that they also affected the numbering formatting. much obliged to you!

Answer (score 1):

With

```
\renewcommand{\makeenmark}{\hbox{$^{[\theenmark]}$}}
```

you add square brackets to the numbers. Just remove that line.